# Looking for advice on analysis plan using a mixed linear regression model

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I am writing the preregistration for a study and I wanted to check whether my analysis plan can be improved.

#### Data description

I attached a picture of some random example data to give you a sense of my data. There will be 80 participants who have different amounts of **Grip Events**. Every participant has 5 grip events during the baseline and then varying amounts during the experiment. Whether a grip occured during the baseline or the experiment is depicted in the **Period** variable. Every grip event has an associated **Grip Strength** and a **Muscle 1** and **Muscle 2** activity. Every participant also has a **Questionnaire1Score** and a **Questionnaire2Score**. Except for the period variable, all variables are continuous. Some participants might have only 1 button press.

[image: Example of my data]

#### Hypotheses and Analyses

As I have repeated testing (possible correlations of results within participants) and different amounts of observations per participant I figured a multilevel/mixed model approach is needed.

*Hypothesis 1*: More Muscle activity for both muscles during the experiment than during baseline.
**Analysis**:  Generalized linear logistic mixed-effects model, where the time period (baseline or experiment) will be predicted by (a) Muscle 1 activity and (b) Muscle 2 activity, which are treated as the fixed effects. The dependencies within one subject would be corrected for by including a random factor for participants, allowing varying intercepts and slopes per participant. This would be implemented in R with something like: `glmer(Period ~ Muscle1 + Muscle2 + (1|Participant), data = mydata, family = binomial)`

*Hypothesis 2*: During the experiment, stronger grip strength goes with higher muscle activity.
**Analysis**: Mixed linear regression model predicting gripper squeeze strength by (a) Muscle 1 activity and (b) Muscle 2 activity, while treating the individuals as random effects with varying intercepts and slopes. This would be implemented in R with something like: `lmer(GripStrength ~ Muscle1 + Muscle2 + (1 | student), data = mydata)` Where I leave out the baseline data by removing them from the dataframe.

*Hypothesis 3*: Higher muscle activity in Muscle1 and Muscle2 predict higher scores on the Questionnaire1 and Questionnaire2.
**Analysis**: Here I am not sure whether to use two seperate mixed linear regression models (one for each questionnaire) or one multivariate approach. But it would look like `lmer(Questionnaire1 ~ Muscle1 + Muscle2 + (1 | student), data = mydata)` Again I leave out the baseline data by removing them from the dataframe.

Am I on the right track? How do I go about centering the electrical muscle activity?

Comment: Can you please post the data excerpt as text, and not as an image?

Comment: I can do that, I am curious: Why is that better?

Comment: It can be searched, it can be copy&pasted, and  ....  Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the numbers and text in your screenshot.